# Como verificar os valores dos registradores pelo gdb?

Tags: debug, gdb

Como verificar o valor de todos os registradores no gdb? Além disso, como verificar o valor de um registrador específico no gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar os valores de todos registradores no gdb, utilize o comando `info all-registers` (ou `i all`). Isto inclui os registradores de ponto flutuante e de vetor. O comando `info registers` (ou `i r`) não exibe registradores de ponto flutuante e de vetor.

Para verificar registradores especificos, utilize `info registers <lista de registradores>`, por exemplo `info registers r1 r2`.

Para imprimir o valor de um registrador, utilize o comando `print $<registrador>`, por exemplo: `p $ebp`.